# ¿Cómo ajustar automaticamente el texto de un textView al tamaño de la pantalla en android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

he buscado sobre dicho tema y no encuentro lo que realmente responde a mi duda. Lo que deseo es que el texto se ajuste automáticamente al ancho de la pantalla del dispositivo en el que se despliegue la aplicación.

Que el resultado en los diferentes resoluciones sea como se muestra en la imagen. Gracias por los aportes que me puedan brindar. El código siguiente es una base a partir del cual se puede llegar a una solución.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="Holaaa"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Esto es lo que deseo realizar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En este enlace se explica como puede afectar la eleccion de DP o SP al tamaño de los textos de tu app. https://www.digitaldot.es/como-evitar-que-cambie-tamano-textos-app/

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo usar las propiedades para [Autosize](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview

Este es un ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:text="TextView autosizing"

    android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    android:autoSizeMinTextSize="12sp"
    android:autoSizeMaxTextSize="100sp"
    android:autoSizeStepGranularity="2sp" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa este [video de Florina Muntenescu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JYrpEAz_A1U) explicando el Autosize.

Answer (score 0):

Para manipular textos existe la medida 'SP' y para los demás componentes 'DP' con estas dos cosas haces que tu aplicación sea 'responsive'

Lo mejor que podes utilizar para crear vistas, en mi opinión, son los contraint layout. Son muy simples e intuitivos, te lo recomiendo!

Usando un constaint layout y un textview solo debes configurar las 'anclas' que es lo que dices a que va a estar sujeto ese componente, por  ejemplo observa este componente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para lo que tu quieres, solamente basta con darle bien las anclas y setear que tu edittext tendra un **width = " match_parent"** o si haces bien las anclas, podras darle **"match_constraint"** la cual es la idea del layout.

Si reusas usar Contraint, solamente con **width = " match_parent"** deberia funcionar

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:text="Holaaa"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    **android:layout_width="match_parent"**
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```